# /bin/sh: How to redirect from &3 to named pipe?

Tags: unix, shell, named-pipes

I have a background process read from named pipe.
for example

`mkfifo /tmp/log.pipe`

`./myprog.sh < /tmp/log.pipe`

I want to use &3 instead of specify /tmp/log.pipe

`echo "aaa" >&3` but results similar to `echo "aaa" > /tmp/log.pipe`

How can I redirect &3 to /tmp/log.pipe everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec 3>/tmp/log.pipe
```

Comment: I tried it but the shell waits for something. I have to Ctrl+C to back to normal. What does it wait?
I use bourne shell

Comment: It's meant to be used in a script.

Comment: oh Thank you. So I have to put `exec 3>/tmp/log.pipe` line in every script? Is there a way to set this globally?

Comment: There is a way around it, but it is *very* hackish, and your scripts will crash if you don't remember to do it each time. It would probably be best if you put it in each individual script that requires it. In short, write a script that does the exec and then invokes a shell.